# Yellow tint over my developed portra 400 film

Tags: film, 35mm, minolta

So one of my relatives gave me their Minolta X-700 with Portra 400 Color Film several weeks ago (no experience in photography), tried it and got it developed.

So just got the digital scan and pictures turned out to look like this:

[image: developed film results]

[image]

So was this outcome caused by using the wrong setting? (like shutter speed, iso, apeture) or is it just a defect within the camera?

also the Minolta X-700 was set to program mode while taking these pictures.

Comment: Need much more info. Tell us how you loaded the film, how old is the film, What were the lighting conditions, did you set the ASA dial on the camera to match the film's ASA ? . As much detail as you can.  *While program mode will set the correct aperture and shutter speed it can only do that if the amount of light falls withing  specific parameters based on the ASA setting*. **PLEASE update your question so we can try to help you**. Also, did you have it developed at a reputable photo lab or a crappy drugstore lab? There appears to more problems than yellow tint. Did you get prints made.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a settings problem. The color shifts and fogging indicate a problem with the film and/or the camera. It looks like a combination of things, IMHO, as someone who shot film for 20 years.

Suspect 1 is old film: it's possible the chemicals on the film were old and less sensitive. Different chemicals aging in different ways would account for color shifts.

Suspect 2 is unwanted light: If you (or your relative) inadvertently opened the back of the camera while film was loaded, you would fog the film as in your first shot. Then, when the lab went to print the image (or scan, in your case), it would try to normalize the exposure to D65 grey and you would end up with a grainy shot that is mostly mid-tones.

If the camera was dropped at some time, and the light integrity of the camera compromised, it would fog the entire roll in weird ways (depending on what light got in).

The second shot looks like it was taken at the beginning of the roll. You can see the film "rebate" with the up arrow (used to orient the negative strip in the darkroom). The tail end of the film doesn't have light-sensitive chemicals on it, and you see an uneven transition to a frame where they start. You can get this by not winding on the film far enough when starting a roll. The right-hand side looks fogged too, as if unwanted light was present. The perfectly vertical transition could be a result of how the film was wound around the take-up roller so the light only affected one part of the image.